# Continuous random variable is a mathematical trick

Tags: probability, statistics

Measuring **real (physical)** events, a random variable can assume only **discrete** values.

Is the use of continuous random variables a **mathematical** trick cause: *it's easier to work with real number ?*

If yes, are you able to explain this in more detail ?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your premise. Remove the randomness from this and consider any continuous process. For instance time. Would you also say that time can only take discrete values? What may be the case is that we can only **measure** time up to a discrete approximation (eg. seconds, nanoseconds etc. depending on the device), but this is not the same as time being discrete. If you agree with this, then there are plenty of random variables that are determined as random times of things, and hence would appear to contradict your claim.

Comment: Are there cases in which a continuous random variables is preferred as "it's easier to work with real number" ? Or it's not true ?

Comment: Continuous variables are easier to work with than discrete variables if the number of possible values the discrete variable can take is large enough, and relatively densely packed. What "large enough" and "relatively densely packed' means is quite vague, though.

Comment: Yes there are these cases. They mostly occur when very large sets of discrete variables are considered. Suppose you are talking about a part of the world's population. Of course this is a discrete number of persons which may take all positive integer values from 1 to 8 billion. So you rather talk about real-valued fractions of the population and do your statistics on those.

Comment: As a person to make a random sound. Would you count the sound they make as a discrete value?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, broadly, with the statement, but also think it rather epically misses the point. It is arguably true that all data we measure in the real world is discrete and that using models with, say, continuous space and time variables is a choice made out of convenience. Why I say the statement above misses the point is because this has nothing specifically to do with probability.

We simply don’t know if space or time are “really” continuous or discrete (but very fine from a macroscopic perspective). There are good reasons from physics to believe that they aren’t continuous microscopically, but I don’t think it matters for the sake of this discussion. All that matters is that continuous space and time are very good models for the macroscopic world.

Then measurement is another layer of abstraction that can introduce discreteness. Again, the operative question is simply how well the discreteness introduced can be approximated as continuous.

You asked about advantages to using continuous approaches, and yes there are some. For one, you don’t have to worry about details about the microscopic elements (what shape the lattice is, etc) and this often cuts down on complexity. Also, quite importantly, calculus is a very useful tool that becomes available in the continuous case. Compare the ease of computing integrals to sums. Also, in the case of probability,  taking a continuum view often simplifies the model. For instance, sometimes the central limit theorem will help you.